# React Native - "Absolute" position and "zIndex" not working on Android

Tags: android, css, ios, react-native, z-index

I'm building a react native app. I have a circular image with text above it which the user can click to go to another page.

This works great on iOS, however on Android I can't click. When I inspect on Android and click the `TouchableHighlight` it seems like the `appBody` view I have as a parent is what's being clicked. I stripped the whole page down and removed the `appBody` leaving just the `TouchableHighlight` and still won't click on Android phones.

I noticed as soon as I remove the `absolute` position from the `viewTextWrap` it then triggers the click! However without the absolute position the `Test` text and background color is behind the image. I was reading absolute position with zIndex causes issue on Android, and to fix this by using `elevation`. So anywhere I have a `Zindex` I added the same `elevation` , but still doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<View style={globalStyle.appBody}>
    <TouchableHighlight style={{zIndex: 100, elevation: 100}} onPress={() => this._goToPage('Test')} underlayColor={'transparent'}>
        <View style={styles.ImageWrap}>
            <Image style={[globalStyle.ProfileImage, { top: -90 }]} source={{ uri: this.state.pic }} defaultSource={require('../../assets/images/placeholder.png')} />
            <Image style={styles.viewImage} source={require('../../assets/images/test.png')} />
            <View style={styles.viewTextWrap}>
                <Text style={styles.viewText}>Test</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>

    //More code in the body here

</View>
```

And the css for those classes:

```
appBody: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 25,
    height: '100%'
},
ImageWrap: {
    position: 'relative',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
},
ProfileImage: {
    position: "absolute",
    zIndex: 100,
    top: -68,
    height: 136,
    width: 136,
    borderRadius: 136 / 2,
    alignSelf: 'center',
},
viewImage: {
    position: "absolute",
    zIndex: 100,
    elevation: 100, //Tried adding to match zIndez
    alignSelf: 'center',
    bottom: -50,
},
viewTextWrap: {
    position: "absolute", //If I remove this, the click works but the text is behind the image
    zIndex: 101,
    elevation: 101, //Tried adding to match zIndez
    alignSelf: 'center',
    bottom: -32,
},
viewText: {
    position: 'relative',
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: "center",
},
```

Comment: Please use position relative to the parent element.

Comment: @TusharKumawat is that for the `appBody` or the `TouchableHighlight` ?

Comment: @TusharKumawat I tried adding position relative on both and still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Instead making position absolute for viewTextWrap, you can use ImageBackground component so that text viewTextWrap doesn't go behind the Image.